# Is there an easy way to copy a variable in the heap into shared memory

Tags: c, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I have a couple of structs with pointers to one another allocated on the heap. I'm converting a multi-threaded program to a multi-process program so I have to make those structs on the heap into shared memory. So far, I've run into nothing but problems on top of problems. MY TA suggested I use memcpy, but I'm not sure that's going to work. Is there any way to convert a set of structs on the heap into shared memory?

Structs I'm using:

```
 struct SharedData {
    int da;
    int         isopen;
    int     refcount;   // reference count:  number of threads using this object
    unsigned int    front;      // subscript of front of queue
    unsigned int    count;      // number of chars in queue
    unsigned int    bufsize;
    pthread_cond_t buffer_full;
    pthread_cond_t buffer_empty;
    pthread_mutex_t mtex;
    fifo_t* queue;
    sem_t       empty_count;

    sem_t       full_count;
    sem_t       use_queue;  // mutual exclusion
};

struct OverSharedData{
    struct SharedData ** rep;
    int rop;
};
```

I malloc'd OverSharedData *, the SharedData structs, and the fifo_t queue, along with multiple char* pointers later on. Do they all have to be declared as shared memory?

Comment: If you're using shared memory, your best bet may be to use offsets into arrays rather pointers.  If the shared memory is at the same address in all processes, and all pointers in the shared memory are pointers to other locations in shared memory, then you can simply copy the data around.  But you can't copy pointers from outside the shared memory in Process A into shared memory and expect Process B to be able to use those pointers — it simply won't work reliably.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler What do you mean by offsets?

Comment: An array index. You define base pointers to the various arrays of structures in the shared memory segment, and you index into those arrays, and you record the array index rather than a pointer. This is often more space economical on 64-bit machines. (How many of your arrays in shared memory have more than 2 billion entries — probably not many, so you can use 32-bit offsets instead of 64-bit pointers.) The biggest advantage is that as long as the base addresses are established correctly, the same offset works even if the base address in Process A is at 0x700000000 and 0x800000000 in Process B.

Answer (score 0):

In the way `malloc()` request memory from heap, there are system calls (for e.g. `shmget()`) to request/create shared memory segment. If your request is successful, you can copy whatever you like over there. (Yes, you can use `memcpy`.) But remember to be careful about pointers, a pointer valid for one process, kept in its shared memory, is not necessarily valid for another process using that shared memory segment.

The shared memory is accessible to all processes for reading and/or writing. If multiple processes are reading/writing to a shared memory segment, then, needless to say, some synchronization techniques (for e.g. semaphore) need to be applied.

Please read up on shared memory. An excellent source is "The Linux Programming Interface" by Michael Kerrisk.

Reference:

- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html
- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmget.2.html
- [http://www.amazon.com/The-Linux-Programming-Interface-Handbook/dp/1593272200](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593272200)

Comment: Do I have to use shmget and shmat every time I want to malloc?

Comment: @AbhishekSaha: Technically yes, but typically no. Typically, you would `shmget()` a big piece of memory and manage it yourself. For example, you can cast it to `struct A`, which, inside, may contain an array of `struct B`